# SQL count huge amount of data

Tags: php, sql, time, database-performance

my MySQL database has over 1 million records and is growing more and more. I have a value 'aid' there which is sometimes available multiple times. I want to count aid.

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT (value) ) AS somevalue
FROM table
```

which worked but now there are so many values that it takes longer than max_exec_time. I also tried the same with GROUP BY without success.

Is there any way to run this query fast? Or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make value a index! Counting a index is much faster then processing records in a table.

Comment: I want the distinct count of 'value'. I do NOT want to know how many entries there are. Do you have a SQL-Query for me that will manage that?

Comment: your value was fine, just add the index: `ALTER TABLE \`table\` ADD INDEX ( \`value\` ) `

Answer (score -1):

Just assign an ID to each row (ID, uto_increment), and take the last ID assigned.